# How can I find text nodes in an HTML snippet?

Tags: php, dom

I'm trying to parse an HTML snippet, using the PHP DOM functions.  I have stripped out everything apart from paragraph, span and line break tags, and now I want to retrieve all the text,  along with its accompanying styles.

So, I'd like to get each piece of text, one by one, and for each one I can then go back up the tree to get the values of particular attributes (I'm only interested in some specific ones, like color etc.).

How can I do this?  Or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: The code could be anything (well, within reason).  It's coming from TinyMCE, and then I'm stripping out everything apart from spans and paragraphs.

Comment: please show the *PHP DOM code* you are using on the *input coming from TinyMCE*

Comment: Currently I'm not doing anything - haven't got that far yet!  I'm trying to work out where to start!

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a DOMDocument here:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/');
```

You can find all text nodes using a simple Xpath.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//text()');
```

Just `foreach` over it to iterate over all textnodes:

```
foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
    echo $textNode->data . "\n";
}
```

From that, you can go up the DOM tree by using `->parentNode`.

Hope that this can give you a good start.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are more comfortable with CSS3 selectors, and are willing to include a single extra PHP class into their project, I would suggest the use of [Simple PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). The solution would look something like the following:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');

$ret = $html->find('p, span');    
$store = array();

foreach($ret as $element) {
    $store[] = array($element->tag => array('text' => $element->innertext, 
                                            'color' => $element->color, 
                                            'style' => $element->style));
}
print_r($store);
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: SimpleHtmlDom uses string parsing? That is something I did not know.

Comment: have a look at it's source ;)